# Webservice pdf file works in Debug but not after publish

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, iis-7

We have a frankenstein webservice that I've been fixing a problem with pdf production and everything is working as expected in Debug but when I publish to the test IIS7 server it runs but I don't get the PDF.

The website callse this function and passes in the claimId

```
Public Function QServices_QAudit_GetWorkersCompCoverPage(ByVal claimId As Long) As Byte()
    Dim sess As General.Session = Session.Item("sessionObject")
    Dim pdfDocument As System.IO.MemoryStream
    If Not AuthorizeUser(sess, Context, "qaudit") Then Return Nothing

    pdfDocument = QAudit.QAuditData.GetWorkersCompCoverPage(claimId, sess)
    If pdfDocument Is Nothing Then Return Nothing

    Dim retValue As Byte()
    ReDim retValue(0 To pdfDocument.Length - 1)
    Dim i As Long
    pdfDocument.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
    For i = 0 To pdfDocument.Length - 1
        retValue(i) = pdfDocument.ReadByte()
    Next

    Return retValue

End Function
```

Which in turn calls a function which reads in a pdf form, populates the fields saves it to the file system then converts it to a memory stream and returns it.  Its converted to a byte stream and sent back to the website.   Everything works great in debug but after publish, the pdf never gets saved.  I'm thinking a permissions issue on either the folder that holds the blank pdf form or the folder that we write the completed form to, but I've given every permission I can think of including Network Services. IUSR, IIS_USRS and Authenticated Users but no change in the result.  I've set the Application pool to Network Service, Local Service, Local System and the default and still no joy.

Any ideas on if there is another permission set I'm missing or something else in IIS7 that is preventing the file reading/writing?

Comment: Hint#1: put a `Using` block around `pdfDocument`

Comment: You should start by adding structured exception handling (try/catch) and reporting the exception that is raised in the production system somewhere (even a text based log file would be better than nothing). If there is no exception then you will know that the issue is in the AuthorizeUser method and you can add logging to see why that is failing.

Comment: curiouser and curiouser as they say.   Seems the site will work if I use Chrome, but if I use IE to look at the beta site it appears to be redirected to the production site.   We're digging through the network policies and IE settings to see if we can find where this behavior might be set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally getting back to this one but learned it was a combination of IIS 7 loosing folder permissions every time we published the website and the app pool permissions of the webservice since it was running on a different level of .net.    Basically we moved the pdf logic from the webservice to the website appcode folder and gave the local iis user permissions on this folder (through IIS, not through windows explorer) and everything is stable.